# displaying words from a txt file in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I have a little problem. I have a text file which contains only English words. I want to display only the words from the file, ignoring spaces.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 50
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char output;
    FILE *p;
    char a[max];
    int i=0;
    p=fopen("thisfile.txt","r");
        while(1)
        {
            char ch=fgetc(p);
            if(ch==EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(ch==' ')
            {
                cout<<a;
                delete [] a;
                            i=0;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i++]=ch;
            }
        }
    fclose(p);
    getch();
}
```

Now I am getting some unexpected characters in output. Can you mention where the problem is ?

Comment: First, use proper English, and second, give us the input data and the expected output.

Comment: delete [] a; Why would you do that? This will have bad results. Really bad.

Comment: The asker seems to think that `delete [] a` will clear the char array so that it can be used for the next word. Tip: It won't. Every `delete` or `delete[]` should have a matching `new` or `new []` and vice versa. You have never allocated an array with `new []`, so you definitely don't need `delete[]`.

Comment: I just noticed that this file is using dramatically **outdated** headers! All standard C++ library headers **don't** use a `.h` suffix. You should probably immediately get rid of whatever C++ tutorial you are using and replace it with one which is only a decade old or, better, yet, an up to date one...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much, *much* simpler solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream infile("thisfile.txt");

    for (std::string word; infile >> word; )
    {
        std::cout << "Got one word: " << word << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can iterate through the words:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("test.txt");
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(file), end;
  for(; begin!= end; ++ begin)
    std::cout<< *begin<< '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your variables aren't initialized. (BTW, `fgetc` returns an **`int`**, it's important to test against `EOF`) An easier solution in standard C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
     if (c == ' ')
         putchar('\n');
     else
         putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   clrscr();
   string s;
   ifstream in("file.txt");

   while(in >> s) {
     cout << s << endl;
   }

   in.close();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to be short and concise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::ifstream("test.txt") >> std::ws),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout));
}
```

Of course, you might want to print something between the words...

Comment: Does it really make sense to have all those `std::` prefixes? To be concise, just put `using namespace std` inside main(). Same goes for the other c++ examples. I know the dogma is not to use `using namespace std`, but if kept within a function it seems the lesser of two evils.

Comment: @WilliamMorris: I found it highly effective for me to always qualify all names (if they can be qualified). In some contexts you need to do so anyway (e.g., to deal with dependent names in templates). The primary reason is that it makes it a lot easier to track where a name is coming from. Of course, I pretty much now what names are in namespace `std` but in real code I typically use a dozens or so additional namespaces in a typical translation unit. Directing people where to look for the definition is helpful in my opinion. I tend to use short namespace aliases, though.

Comment: Point taken :-)  I'm learning C++ (from a C background) and I find these long strings containing repeated `std::` drive me up the wall!